# Diferencias entre contentColor y containerColor en Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy trabajando con android studio, Compose, Kotlin, y tengo ciertos problemas para identificar las diferencias entre ContentColor y ContainerColor.

```
@Composable
fun LoginButton() {
    Button(
        onClick = {},
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(48.dp), colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            containerColor = Color(0xFFF44336),
            disabledContainerColor = Color(0xFFF443367870),
            contentColor = Color.White,
            disabledContentColor = Color.Cyan
        )
    ) {
        Text(text = "inician sesion")
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues uno es el color del contenido, texto y demás, y el otro el color del contenedor. Lo suyo es que te mires el theme builder, y ahí tienes todos los colores como te quedarían.

Answer (score 1):

Si vemos [el código fuente del botón](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Button.kt;l=106), resulta que le pasa los colores a un **Surface**. Entonces miremos [su documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Surface(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,kotlin.Function0)).

Esta nos dice lo siguiente:

> Background: Surface fills the shape specified by shape with the color.
> If color is ColorScheme.surface a color overlay will be applied. The
> color of the overlay depends on the tonalElevation of this Surface,
> and the LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation set by any parent surfaces. This
> ensures that a Surface never appears to have a lower elevation overlay
> than its ancestors, by summing the elevation of all previous Surfaces.
>
> Content color: Surface uses contentColor to specify a preferred color
> for the content of this surface - this is used by the Text and Icon
> components as a default color.

En español, que `color` se utiliza para el fondo del **Surface** y `contentColor` como color preferido para el contenido (por ejemplo, texto e íconos).

Sería como el `background` y `color` de CSS. Por ejemplo, un botón amarillo con texto naranja:

```css
button {
   background: #ffd47a;
   color: #ff6900;
}
```

```html
<button>Hola</button>
```